# Add time between rows and only take specific row in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I don't know what this would be called but I am looking to only get the first row for a specific field. And then I'd like to calculate the time between rows.

In this example there should only be 1 status 1 and 1 status 2 for each patient. That is part one. Then I'd like to combine (I was thinking maybe an unpivot?) and get the time difference..

```
Patient Status  Time Stamp
--------------------------
A       Status1 22:36:45
A       Status2 23:04:13
A       Status2 3:43:13
B       Status1 10:22:42
B       Status2 10:32:47
C       Status1 16:14:30
C       Status2 16:43:41
C       Status2 17:22:49
```

This is the outcome I'd like

```
Patient Time Between Status 1&2 
-------------------------------
A           0:27:28 
B           0:10:05 
C           0:29:11
```

Comment: How do you chose row if there are several status 2 rows for a patient?

Comment: They are chronological - so I need the first one that comes after the status 1..

Comment: What is the order of your data that you can figure `the first one that comes after ...` ?

Comment: It's already ordered by patient and then timestamp. But if it wasn't I'd need the Status 2 that chronologically comes after the Status 1 time stamp..

Comment: You don't need an unpivot, a self-join will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use analytic function [FIRST_VALUE and LAG](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213234.aspx):

```
first_value(time_stamp) OVER(PARTITION BY patient, status ORDER BY time_stamp) first_val

lag(time_stamp) OVER(PARTITION BY patient ORDER BY status) previos_val
```

Then just get difference beetween first_val and previous_val.

Example (tested on OracleDB):

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT patient, status, time_stamp,
       first_value(time_stamp)
       OVER(PARTITION BY patient, status ORDER BY time_stamp) first_val,
       lag(time_stamp) OVER(PARTITION BY patient ORDER BY status) previos_val
  FROM (
    SELECT 'A' Patient, 'Status1' status,
      to_date('2015-04-07 22:36:45', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') time_stamp 
    FROM dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'A' Patient, 'Status2' status,
      to_date('2015-04-07 23:04:13', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') time_stamp
    FROM dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'A' Patient, 'Status2' status,
      to_date('2015-04-07 3:43:13', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') time_stamp
    FROM dual
  )
)
WHERE time_stamp = first_val
ORDER BY patient, status;
```

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't mention this is in 2008. I'm pretty sure First Value is 2012

Answer (score 0):

You can use ROW_NUMBER() to get the row of status 2 that comes after the status 1.

```
SELECT A.Patient
,CONVERT(varchar(8),CAST(B.TimeStamp as DATETIME)-CAST(A.TimeStamp as DATETIME),8) as Time
FROM yourtable A
JOIN 
(
    SELECT Patient,TimeStamp
    ,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by Patient ORDER BY Status) as ROWID
    FROM yourtable WHERE Status='Status2'
) B 
ON A.Patient=B.Patient AND B.ROWID=1
WHERE A.Status='Status1'
ORDER BY A.Patient
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Patient Time
A       00:27:28
B       00:10:05
C       00:29:11
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do a simple `GROUP BY`, and calculate the difference between (first) status2 and (first) status1:

```
select Patient,
       min(case when Status = 'Status2' then timestamp end) -
          min(case when Status = 'Status1' then timestamp end)
from tablename
group by patient
```

Note that I don't know MS SQL Server, so you'll probably have to adjust the time difference calculation. (Look at the other answers!)